# Using -f operator on a string that contains curly braces

Tags: string, powershell, formatting, powershell-3.0

Consider the following here-string that I am trying to use a template for my Nagios definitions.

```
$blankDefinition = @"
define host{
        use             windows-server  ; Inherit default values from a template
        host_name       {0}       ; The name we're giving to this host
        alias           {0}       ; A longer name associated with the host
        address         {1}     ; IP address of the host
        }

"@
```

I have a script that determines which of my servers are not in nagois that should be. As it loops I'm trying to have it spit out a definion for me so that I can copy and paste into my Nagios config.

```
$comparison | %{
    $blankDefinition -f $($_.serverName),$($_.ipAddress)
}
```

Which nets me the following error:

```
Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format..
```

Something like this works just fine

```
@"
Testing
One
{0}
Three
"@ -f "Twelve"
```

So then I found out that it is because of the other curly braces. Is there a way that i can format my string using the -f while keeping the braces? Or do i have to use variable subsitution only?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Adding another set of curly braces seems to work:

```
$blankDefinition = @"
define host{{
        use             windows-server  ; Inherit default values from a template
        host_name       {0}       ; The name we're giving to this host
        alias           {0}       ; A longer name associated with the host
        address         {1}     ; IP address of the host
        }}

"@

$blankDefinition -f 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'
```

Output:

```
define host{
        use             windows-server  ; Inherit default values from a template
        host_name       foo       ; The name we're giving to this host
        alias           foo       ; A longer name associated with the host
        address         bar     ; IP address of the host
        }
```

Comment: Never even occured to me to escape them. Thanks.