# How can I do variable substitution in a here-string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pull the items from the array in `$IOC`, and then for each item replace the $IMPORT in $API here-string and echo the result to the console, and then do that for each item in the `$IOC` array.

```cs
#put IOC's into array
$IOC= ‘c:\Users\powershell_array.txt'
#api curl script with variable to be replaced
$API = @"
curl --insecure 'https://192.168.1.1:3000/hx/api/v2/indicators/Custom/Powershell_AD/conditions/execution' -X 'POST' --data-binary "
{  
   \"tests\":[  
       {  
         \"token\":\"processEvent/ActiveDirectory\",
         \"type\":\"text\",
         \"operator\":\"contains\",
         \"preservecase\":false,
         \"value\":\"$IMPORT\"
      }
   ]
}" -H 'X-FeApi-Token:   IAOaiq1s2' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'"
"@

ForEach ($i in Get-Content $IOC) {$API -replace $IMPORT, $i} echo $API
```

I don't get an error but it just prints the contents of the array and then of course echo's `$API` one time without the replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$IMPORT` will be evaluated and expanded as soon as the here-string is assigned to `$API`.

Change it to a literal here-string (`'` instead of `"`) and remember to escape the `\$` in the `-replace` pattern argument:

```
$API = @'
curl --insecure 'https://192.168.1.1:3000/hx/api/v2/indicators/Custom/Powershell_AD/conditions/execution' -X 'POST' --data-binary "
{  
   \"tests\":[  
       {  
         \"token\":\"processEvent/ActiveDirectory\",
         \"type\":\"text\",
         \"operator\":\"contains\",
         \"preservecase\":false,
         \"value\":\"$IMPORT\"
      }
   ]
}" -H 'X-FeApi-Token:   IAOaiq1s2' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'"
'@

foreach ($i in Get-Content $IOC) {
    $API -replace '\$IMPORT', $i
}
```

Comment: Both really helped, unfortunately I can't give points yet but it is much appreciated.!!!

Answer (score 5):

[Mathias has it right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39599647/3829407) about when the variable would be evaluated. Another approach that would allow for the same logic that you intended is to use the [format operator](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html). Update your string to contain place holders for your various (1 in this case) variables that we can then substitute while in the loop. We use `{n}` (in this case `{0}`) and feed an array of equal size to the number of place holders.

```
$API = @'
curl --insecure 'https://192.168.1.1:3000/hx/api/v2/indicators/Custom/Powershell_AD/conditions/execution' -X 'POST' --data-binary "
{{  
   \"tests\":[  
       {{  
         \"token\":\"processEvent/ActiveDirectory\",
         \"type\":\"text\",
         \"operator\":\"contains\",
         \"preservecase\":false,
         \"value\":\"{0}\"
      }}
   ]
}}" -H 'X-FeApi-Token:   IAOaiq1s2' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'"
'@

ForEach ($i in Get-Content $IOC){$API -f $i}
```

No regex overhead is needed however for this approach to work you will need to double up any curly braces already present in the string. A little embarrassing for me to forget since [I had that problem in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436058/using-f-operator-on-a-string-that-contains-curly-braces).

Comment: I thought so too, initially. Except the `{}` literals in the string interferes with the format placeholders :-\

Comment: Both the outer object and the inner object in `tests`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks again. I feel silly since I knew that could happen but wasn't looking for them when I answered.