# Pass list to html in powershell using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, powershell

Hi I have a HTML code inside a powershell script which I want to run using listener. When I pass direct values to an element in html, it works. But when I pass a list and use for loop the data returned is blank. It actually takes the first element of the list. Is there any other way to do it???
Please help. Thanks...

```html
$show = ['a','b']

$html = @"
<html>
   <head>
   <title>My Web Shell</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Browse Files</h1>
      <a id = "demo"></a>
      <script>
      var files = {{0}};
      var dir = '';
      var i;
      for(i = 0; i < files.count; i++){{
          dir += files[i] + "<br>";
       }}
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
      </script>
       
   </body>
"@ -f $show
```

Thanks @Matt your link helped me to solve the curly braces issue.

Comment: You should be escaping you curly braces that are _not_ part of the format string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436058/using-f-operator-on-a-string-that-contains-curly-braces

Comment: Also `$show = ['a','b']` is not right. Should that be quoted?

Comment: Hi @Matt thanks the issue is solved. But I am not able to pass the list value. So the javascript dosen't work. Is there any possible way to do it???